# can't reach to section in json file

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to retrieve the selection in an adaptive card of a `json` file.
So when the allergic option `'peanut'` is selected, I want to assign it to a variable. But the code keeps throwing an error.

Adaptive card code:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "speak": "...",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.0",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Almost there...",
                        "size": "large",
                        "weight": "bolder"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                        "title": "Beef",
                        "card": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "What are you allergic to?",
                                    "size": "medium",
                                    "wrap": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                                    "value": "BeefAllergy",
                                    "id": "BeefAllergy",
                                    "style": "expanded",
                                    "isMultiSelect": false,
                                    "isCompact": false,
                                    "choices": [
                                        {
                                            "title": "Peanut",
                                            "value": "peanut"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "title": "Seafood",
                                            "value": "seafood"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                                    "title": "Next",
                                    "data": {
                                        "mealOptions": "beef"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to store it in a variable:

```
lunchAllergy= session.message.attachments.content.actions.card.body[1].choices[1].value
session.send(lunchallergy)
```

And here's the error:

> ERROR: Cannot read property 'actions' of undefined

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/matthidinger/ContosoScubaBot) is in c# but it may help you because it uses JSON adaptive cards.  It has a card doing almost the exact same thing.  [Test it here](https://contososcubabot.azurewebsites.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test with your adaptive card content, actually, when your user click the `Action.Submit` button, your bot can get users selection in the `session.message.value`, and you can store what you want in variables.

[image]

You can refer to the sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards/app.js for details.